# Solving a logarithmic equation. I need help on solving them when they are in exponents.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$x^{\large  2\log^3x-3/2\log x}=\sqrt{10}$$  Can someone help me to solve it?

Also, when we have $2\log^2 x$, is it equal to $4(\log x)^2$

Comment: Edit plz :-) ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: Do you see the "share edit flag" text at the bottom of your question?  Click on the word "edit."

Comment: I doubt that it's possible to solve that equation, other than approximately. Make sure you have the right equation.

Comment: Assuming your equation is
$$x\log(x)(2(\log x)^2-3/2)=\sqrt{10},$$
then let $y=\log x$. Then $$ye^y(4y^2-3)=2\sqrt{10}.$$ Solve for $y$ if possible.

Comment: $2\log^2 x = 2(\log (x))^2 \neq 4(\log (x))^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that with $\log$ you mean the decimal logarithm, your equation is equivalent to
$$
\log(x^t)=\log\sqrt{10}
$$
where $t=2(\log x)^3-\frac{3}{2}\log x$, so to
$$
t\log x=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
Note that I wrote the clearer $(\log x)^3$ rather than the ambiguous $\log^3x$, but it's just a matter of conventions.

Now, set $y=\log x$ and rewrite your equation by substituting $t=2y^3-\frac{3}{2}y$:

> \begin{align}\left(2y^3-\frac{3}{2}y\right)y=\frac{1}{2}\end{align} which shouldn't be too difficult to solve (it's a biquadratic).

Answer (score 1):

Your equation [has solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%282%5Clog%5E3x-3/2%5Clog%20x%29=%5Csqrt%7B10%7D) (link to Wolfram Alpha), but given the tag that's been used, I suspect that you or your problem list has a typo in the transcription of the problem.

Regarding your question: $$2 \log^3 x = 2(\log x)^3 \neq 4(\log x)^2$$  If we had $2 \log (x^3),$ then  $$2 \log (x^3)=\log\Big({(x^3)}^2\Big) = \log(x^6)$$